# Question closed, stated it should be more focused, which it is

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

A few days ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398564/website-talking-to-native-app-via-localhost-cors-https-problems) and this morning it got closed.

The reason is (quote)

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers.

IMHO the question is as focused as it gets. It clearly states a specific problem and the ways I tried workarounds.

Why did it get closed? What specifically should I change in order to get it reopened?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _specific_ questions about code. Your question contains no code at all, and asks for very broad architectural design advice (which smacks of opinion-based, too).

Comment: @tripleee My question doesn't contain any code because I'm asking for a code that would "fix" my problem (if I had the "code" I wouldn't be asking in the first place). My question does contain "what I tried so far" (which also doesn't have any code as I'm describing architectural decisions / problems that invalidate what I have tried so far). My questions doesn't seem to be broad at all: it's actually very targeted. It targets a specific browser and it targets a specific limitation/bug of that browser (and I have also linked the bug report of Safari's tracker).

Comment: People get paid much money for answering questions like that as consultants.

Comment: Note that as asked question looks like you are installing some backdoor on the user machines accessible from any site/browser... Cutting that out of the question could be better (sometimes real use case is way fishier that fake one - like if you just narrowed it down to your own debugging/experiments)

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the question is based on a flawed premise, and answering it would mean saying "you are doing it wrong, there are other ways of doing it correctly but you'd have to rewrite a lot of your application, and the specifics of how to rewrite it would be too broad and opinion based for our Q&A format".

You are trying to:

- use a client application running on the end-users's machine (what you call a "native" application in your question) to run a web server (what you call "a localhost server")
- serve HTML on a different web server which is consumed by a different client application (the web browser), which in turn triggers AJAX requests to the original client application running on the end-user's machine

This is uniquely wrong, and answers (such as mine here), are bound to be very broad, impractical and opinionated. This stems from a poor design, and it seems you are not going to be convinced that your design is wrong and that you should rethink it.

If the client application needs information from the remote web server it should request it. Either by making its own HTTP requests, or by some sort of "subscriber" system if you need server initiated events. Think [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or something like [Mercure](https://mercure.rocks/).

If you do **not** need to react to server-side-events, and instead you just want to react to user-initiated-events (which would explain the AJAX approach, where you simply are hosting the client remotely and the server locally), then the better approach would be to simply host the client on the same client application that hosts the local web server. HTML, JavaScript and API would all be on the same server, which would eliminate all the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and mixed contents problems and everything work fine, although probably on a non-standard port (e.g. `http://localhost:19898`). Yours wouldn't be the first application to use this approach.

When a question is based on a basically wrong approach, and the path to fixing the correct approach would require a big architectural rethink and rewrite, the question can be too much for a site like this.

Comment: While I have contemplated the option of hosting my website (HTML) from my application, this has several drawbacks. Furthermore, you keep insisting that my current approach is flawed, but the thing is it's not, and there are some good examples of this use case in the Safari's bug report that I have linked in my initial question. Either way, why close-vote the question? Why not just answer with "you should do XYZ instead"?

Comment: Some other Stack Exchange sites [don't have a problem with very broad questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/550634).

Comment: True,  @Peter, different sites have different rules and expectations. Some even field questions about software recommendations.